# Sequence on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the evenly spaced integer topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, integers

I find some problems in solving this exercise:

> Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the evenly spaced integer topology. Prove that the sequence $a_n = n!$ converges to zero.

My reasoning is: let $S(a,k)=a + k \mathbb{Z}= \left \{ a+kn: n \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$, with $a,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a generic arithmetic progression. Then, we have to prove that for any sequence $S(0,k)$ we have $a_n \in S(0,k)$ definitively.

But, how can we prove the last part, i.e., $\exists n_0$ such that $a_n \in S(0,k) \quad \forall n >n_0$? And how can we show a counterexample, for instance $a_n$ does not converge to 3?

Answer (score 3):

Because $n\geqslant k\implies n!\in S(0,k)$, since $k\mid n!$ then.

And you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}n!=3$ (or any other number different from $0$), because $\Bbb Z$, endowed with that topology is separated, and therefore a sequence can have, at most, one limit.

Comment: Do you mean, $\frac{n!}{k}=\frac{n(n-1) \dots (k+1)k(k-1) \dots 1}{k}= n(n-1) \dots (k+1)(k-1) \dots 1 \in S(0,k), \forall n \geq k$?

Comment: That is correct, but I was simply thinking that, if $n\geqslant k$, then $n!$ is the product of several numbers, one of which is $k$. Therefore, $k\mid n!$.

Comment: of course, the core of the esercise is somewhat easy.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure. I meant “separated”, not “separable”. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question has already been answered, so I will address the second.

To show $a_n$ does not converge to $3$, it suffices to find an arithmetic progression $S(3,k)$ such that for every $n_0$, there exists $n>n_0$ such that $a_n\notin S(3,k)$. In other words, we can find terms arbitrarily far out in the sequence $a_n$ that are not in $S(3,k)$.

Take $k=2$ so $S(3,k) = \{...,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,...\}$. Then we can find arbitrarily large terms in the sequence $a_n=n!$ that are not in $S(3,k)$ since for all $n \geq 2$, $n!$ is even.

This exact argument won't work for every possible choice of limit (only odd limits). I'd have to put in a bit more thought to come up with a direct proof that $a_n$ does not converge to, say, $2$ or $4$. However, the integers with the evenly spaced topology [are a Hausdorff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evenly_spaced_integer_topology#Properties), and so limits of sequences must be unique.

Comment: without using the theory, if I'm not wrong we have to show, let's say $n! \notin S(2,3)$ for any $n > n_0$. In this case it must be $\frac{n!}{2+3m} \notin S(2,3)$ with $m \in  \mathbb{N}$, for any $n > n_0$. Right? But how to show that clearly?

Comment: Where did $S(2,3)$ come from? Are you talking about showing the sequence does not converge to $2$ now?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to show that $n!$ does not converge to a value different from zero. $S(2,3)$ is just meant to provide a counterexample.

Comment: Notice that no element of $S(2,3)$ is divisible by $3$ (they are all congruent to $2$ modulo $3$). Eventually every factorial must be divisible by $3$, so for sufficiently large $n$ (in fact just $n>3$), $n! \notin S(2,3)$. I'm not sure why you've written $\frac{n!}{2+3m} \notin S(2,3)$ - it should either be $\frac{n!}{2+3m} \notin \mathbb{Z}$ or $n! \notin S(2,3)$.

Comment: In fact this will give the proof in general that $n!$ does not converge to $k$ - consider the arithmetic progression $S(k,k+1)$. None of these elements are divisible by $k+1$, but for sufficiently large $n$, $n!$ must be divisible by $k+1$, so $n! \notin S(k,k+1)$.

Comment: We have $S(k,k+1)=\left \{ k, k \pm(k+1), k\pm2(k+1), k\pm3(k+1) \right \}$, then if $n! \in S(k,k+1)$, $n!$ should be divisibile by $k+m(k+1)$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If we consider $k=1$ and $m=1$, $k+m(k+1)=3$ and $n!$ is divisibile by 3.

Comment: That's not quite right - to have $n! \in S(k,k+1)$ you need $n!$ to be *equal to* $k+m(k+1)$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, not just divisible by it. Those are not equivalent statements. With your example $k=1$, we have $S(k,k+1)=S(1,2) = \{\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5...\}$. Note none of these are divisible by $k+1=2$, so none of them can be equal to $n!$ when $n \geq 2$.